# What is the difference between Memory footprint, Javascript memory and live memory in Chrome Task Manager?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, windows-10, google-chrome-devtools

I am using Chrome v73. I have a memory leak in my web application. I can see all mentioned parameters increasing drastically. I want to know what it is and which one I can refer to and fix accordingly.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/